# how to make collectd python plugin to use python3 instead of python2 to execute the script

Tags: python, collectd

I have enable python collectd plugin. My python script requires python3 syntax. When the script executes it is using python2.7 hence my script fails. How can I force the plugin to use python3 instead of python2.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to recompile collectd to in order to make it use python 3.x
Take a look at these:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/642893/using-collectd-with-python-3
- https://github.com/collectd/collectd/issues/3192